# Add border when setting wrap panel in an itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I'm using `ItemsControl`, and set `ItemsPanel` to `WrapPanel`, so I can show the data in multi-columns. Now I want to add a border to each item, just like `DataGrid`.
But the border always overlapping. So how to set each border thickness to 1.0?

I tried to set `myBorder`'s `BorderThickness` to `1 0.5 1 0.5`, it works. But not the best way.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" Margin="12 0 0 0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="20" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: or use 1,1 and set the margin to 0,-1,0,0 so they overlap

Comment: Seems not working. See https://imgur.com/a/G2gciBG

Comment: try again but add  Margin="0,1,0,0" to the wrappanel   <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="0,1,0,0"/>

Comment: It works, can you put it in the answer. Thx.

Comment: Done :)
Glad i could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving them all border of one px "1,1" and a margin of "0,-1,0,0". This will make them all have a full border but they will overlap giving the impression of just a single one beeing present at the touching faces.
To prevent the top part of the first element to disappear you'll also need to set the margin of the wrappanel to "0,1,0,0"
Example below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1,1" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Margin="12 0 0 0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="20" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```